# The union of weighted compact supported continuous function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ be open. Given a weight function $v\geq 1$ such that $v\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ and $l.s.c$. Also supposethere exists a Lipschitz continuous sequence $v_n$ such that $1\leq v_n\leq v$ and $v_n\nearrow v$ for all $x\in\Omega$. Note that $v$ may not bounded above.

Define $C_c(\Omega,v):=\{u\in C(\Omega), u/v\in C_c(\Omega)\}$.

My question: do we have
$$
C_c(\Omega,v)\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_c(\Omega,v_n),
$$
or, in another words, for any $f\in C_c(\Omega,v)$ there exists a $n_0$ such that $f\in C_c(\Omega,v_{n_0})$?

---

I realize that the above argument is trivial as I set $v\in L^1_{\text{loc}}$. To make question more interesting, I delete the assumption that $v\in L^1_{\text{loc}}$ and hence $v$ could be $+\infty$ over a positive measure set. Now $u/v\in C_c(\Omega)$ no longer makes $u$ is compact supported. Now, is my claim still hold?

Comment: Your last sentence asks about the $\subset$ direction of the equality, but the $\supset$ direction need not hold.  Consider something like $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, $v = 1+1_{(0, +\infty)}$.  You can take $v_n$ to be 1 on $(-\infty, 0]$, 2 on $[1/n, +\infty)$, and linear in between.  If you take $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ which is 1 in a neighborhood of 0, then $f \in C_c(\Omega, v_n)$ for every $n$, but $f \notin C_c(\Omega, v)$.

Comment: I do not get the question: Apparently $C_c(\Omega)$ is the space of continuous functions with compact support. But $u$ and $u/v$ have the same support so that $C_c(\Omega,v)=C_c(\Omega)$???

Comment: @JochenWengenroth: you are right. Actually we we have $C_c(\Omega,\nu)\subset C_c(\Omega)$. Think, as Nate point out above, the case that $\nu$ is not continuous. Then $u/v$ maybe compact supported but not continuous. I modified my post a bit, although it looks trivial now...

Comment: @NateEldredge I modified my post a bot. Well, as $v$ has to be a.e. finite since $v\in L^1_{\text{loc}}$, it makes $u$ has to be compactly supported if $u\in C_c(\Omega,\nu)$ and hence $u\in C_c(\Omega)$ as Jochen point out. Hence, my claim holds trivially. Am I right?

Comment: @NateEldredge I also update my post a bit. Welcome to have a look!

Comment: What about constant weights $v=\infty$ and $v_n=n$?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth It assumed that $v$ is $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ at least.

Comment: But you wrote: *To make question more interesting, I delete the assumption that $v\in L^1_{loc}$ and hence $v$ could be $+\infty$ over a positive measure set.*

Comment: @JochenWengenroth ah sorry my bad. Certainly you are right. if you use constant weight, $C_c(\Omega) = C_c(\Omega,v_n)$ always. But in this case $C_c(\Omega,\infty)$ is just $C(\Omega)$ itself.